# pictures on a sub-domain or separate domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, image-gallery

I was given a suggestion to put our vast picture gallery into separate subdomain, or even separate domain. I dont see how it would help, but I do know that meny other sites does it.
Anyone could point me to the right direction concerning this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two biggest reasons for this are

1. to use a CDN (Content Delivery Network) to maximize your user's experience through delivering static files faster
2. To better utilize specific hardware.  For example, your web server may be super beefy, running on SSDs (relatively small capacity), 16GB RAM etc. that you don't want to have to bog down with serving millions of extra files.  Your image server would only need a very weak computer but could very inexpensively be backed by 10 TB of storage.

Comment: Is there anything to do with the number of connections per domain or anything ? This might sound silly but thats the usual purpose for this  I get when people tell me about this.

Comment: The more connections you have to a single domain, the more memory and processing power is unnecessarily used because more instances of your server (Apache for most of us) need to be spawned.  That is a big part of #2 above.
Browsers also have a limit to the amount of simultaneous connections they can make, but that limit is not per domain, so it would be irrelevant.